# Angular Select value not working

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I have an angular table with a list of *objects*.
This list is defined in my controller. I also have a list of *items* defined in my controller.
My items list contains an item with the id equal to the object id.
I use the same list of items for the ng-option of all select.

I have got 3 issues :

1. The selected value is not set
2. When I select an element in the select, object.ItemId is not the id of the item but the item itself
3. When I select an element in the select, the first element is always marked as selected even if I select another

Here my html code

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.Items = [{Name: 'Itm 1', Id: 1},{Name: 'Itm 2', Id: 2},{Name: 'Itm 3', Id: 3}];
  $scope.Items2 = [{Name: 'Itm2 1', Id: 1},{Name: 'Itm2 2', Id: 2},{Name: 'Itm2 3', Id: 3}];
  $scope.Objects = [{Name: 'Obj 1', Id: 1, ItemId: 2, ItemId2: 3},{Name: 'Obj 2', Id: 2, ItemId: 2, ItemId2: 2},{Name: 'Obj 3', Id: 3, ItemId: 3, ItemId2: 2}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyController">
    <table class="@DefaultTableClass">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="object in Objects">
                <td>
                    <select type="text" ng-model="object.ItemId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Item is required" name="Objects[{{$index}}].ItemId" ng-options="item.Name for item in Items track by item.Id" class="form-control">
                    </select>
                    <span>{{object.ItemId}}</span>
                    <span data-valmsg-for="Objects[{{$index}}].ItemId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" ng-model="object.ItemId2" data-val="true" data-val-required="Item2 is required" name="Objects[{{$index}}].ItemId2" ng-options="item.Name for item in Items2 track by item.Id" class="form-control">
                    </select>
                    <span>{{object.ItemId2}}</span>
                    <span data-valmsg-for="Objects[{{$index}}].ItemId2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add some js code or for better clarity can you please provide plunker or fiddle?

Comment: Please refer docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select
Please implement select in angular way

Comment: Just edit my question and add code

Comment: I reckon this what you want : https://plnkr.co/edit/KbaeLBf1Ij4X4IPAiqF9?p=preview Have a look and let me know

Comment: Was it what you want?

Comment: I simplify to much my code. Actually, I have 2 select. If I set the object as the ng-model, changing the selected element will change all the object not only the attribute of my object... So if I change Item, Item2 will also change...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code, while selecting value your actual **object** variable is replace by **item** variable so its not able to find itemId attribute,you need to change ng-options to correct way depends on what you want as select value and what you want as label.

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyController">
    <table class="@DefaultTableClass">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="object in Objects">
                <td>
                    <select type="text" ng-model="object" data-val="true" data-val-required="Item is required" name="Objects[{{$index}}]" ng-options=" item as item.Name  for item  in Items track by item.Id" class="form-control">
                    </select>
                    <span>{{object.Id}}</span>
                    <span data-valmsg-for="Objects[{{$index}}].ItemId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Working Code - > [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/694uszty/46/)

Comment: I simplify to much my code for the explanation. I have 2 select in the <td>
Passing object to the ng-model will change the 2 select instead of changing the attribute of my object (I change my code in my question)